# Freeze on boot on grub2 screen

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows

I need the help of the community because I have a problem when I boot my computer.

Immediately after pushing the button, I have this screen, where all is stuck and freezed. I can’t Pick a partition to boot on. To select one of them I have to restart the computer and press escape key to access on this other screen (joined) to boot normally. With enter and I can select now the partition.

How can I do to be allowed to select directly the partition at startup without all this manipulations.

grub stuck:

[image: grub stuck]

After pressing escape:

[image: after pressing escape]

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Installing [boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows) on a Live USB will probably fix it. It worked for me after disabling Optional Legacy ROM support in BIOS when all the grub menu options broke.

Comment: You're welcome. Please update us with progress. Also you could try the grub menu option `Windows Boot Manager for /dev/nmve0n1p1` to run Windows 10 instead.